# How to cancel previous axios request?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

How can I cancel the previous axios request in React/Redux when I create a new request?

Here is one of the options I found on Google, but it doesn't work.

**action.js**

```
class FilmsActions {
  getFilmList(searchParams = undefined, cancelToken = null) {
    return async dispatch => {
      dispatch(filmsFetchRequest());
      try {
        const res = await api.get(`/films/${searchParams && searchParams}`, {
          cancelToken,
        });
        return setTimeout(() => dispatch(filmsFetchSuccess(res.data)), 1000);
      } catch (err) {
        return setTimeout(() => dispatch(filmsFetchError(err)), 1000);
      }
    }
  }
}

export const filmsActions = new FilmsActions();
```

**app.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

class BrowseFilms extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {    
    const {
      getFilmList,
      location,
      loading,
    } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.location.search !== location.search) {    
      if (loading) {
        this.source.cancel();
      }

      this.source = axios.CancelToken.source();

      getFilmList(location.search, this.source.token);
    }
  }

  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.films.data,
  loading: state.films.loading,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getFilmList: (searchParams, cancelToken) => dispatch(filmsActions.getFilmList(searchParams, cancelToken)),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BrowseFilms));
```

In this case, it does not cancel the request. If you swap (in componentDidUpdate) `if (loading)` and `this.source`, then it will cancel the request, but the next request, not the previous request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in cases when the server returned the response too quickly and there was nothing to cancel.

To avoid this you need to change the action.js.

**action.js**

```
const delay = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

class FilmsActions {
  getList(searchParams = undefined, cancelToken = null) {
    return async dispatch => {
      dispatch(filmsFetchRequest());
      try {
        await delay(1000);
        const res = await api.get(`/films/${searchParams && searchParams}`, {
          cancelToken,
        });
        return dispatch(filmsFetchSuccess(res.data));
      } catch (err) {
        if (!axios.isCancel(err)) {
          return dispatch(filmsFetchError(err));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export const filmsActions = new FilmsActions();
```